# Conditional expectation in Cambridge stats notes

Tags: statistics

I am going over [these](http://www.statslab.cam.ac.uk/~rrw1/stats/Sa4.pdf), page 15.

They say that the optimal estimator is $$\lambda^* = \mathbb{E} \left[ X_1 \Bigg| \sum_i X_i= t\right]$$

I fail to understand how to evaluate this expectation. I also fail to understand why

$$\mathbb{E}\left[ \sum_i X_i \Bigg| \sum_{i}X_i = t\right] = t$$

TL;DR:

$X_1, ..., X_n \sim P(\lambda)$, they are IID and $T(X) = \sum_i X_i = t$ is a sufficient statistic.

Comment: For your second expression, it is of the form $\mathbb E[Y \mid Y=y]$ which is clearly $y$

Comment: why? I do not know how to evaluate conditional expectation

Comment: If you knew that $Y=y$ then the conditional expectation of $Y$ would be $y$.  You can find out about conditional probability and conditional expectation in notes for the [Probability Part Ia course](http://www.statslab.cam.ac.uk/~rrw1/prob/prob-weber.pdf), a precursor of these Statistics Part Ib course notes.

Comment: And the notes then tell you how to evaluate the first expression.  Since the $X_i$ are independently and identically distributed and since expectation is linear, the second expression is $n$ times the first expression, making the first expression $\dfrac{t}{n}$

Comment: @Henry ahh. I'll have a look at those. Thanks